# How to Reset default all the json settings for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I changed all the settings  file (launch.json , task.json , c_cpp_properties.json) in visual studio Code, in order to run c++ programs with it, But I failed miserably , After re installing it , the settings file were not cleared they still remain the same. How do I reset it to default i.e factory reset. 
And also If possible, How could I configure them to build and run c++, programs through console/ terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try clearing/removing/renaming settings file. This should force vscode use default settings